# holoviews+datashader in bokeh server resets when zooming

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying to put a datashaded plot in a bokeh server dashboard I'm working on. It mostly works, except when I try to zoom in on the y-axis of the plot it will "reset". I've managed to make this script which reproduces the problem I am having. My relevant environment is:

```
bokeh = 0.12.11
datashader = 0.6.3
holoviews = 1.9.1-x-gc1d66c015
```

Here is the code, that I serve with `bokeh serve test.py`. I am also running this on a remote machine, and using an SSH tunnel as described in the bokeh server documentation. The almost identical code runs fine in jupyter notebook, running on the same machine. So I suspect it is either a problem or a configuration I am missing in bokeh server.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import holoviews as hv
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datashader as ds
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, dynspread
import holoviews.plotting.bokeh  # noqa (Activate backend)

def read_data():
    t = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', freq='1T', periods=1e6)
    x = np.arange(t.size)
    y1 = np.cos(x / 100)
    y2 = 10 + np.sin(x / 100)

    classes = list(range(1, 15))
    class_list = []
    for c in classes:
        class_list += [c] * 100
        cluster = class_list * (t.size // 100 + 1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(cluster=cluster[:t.size],
                                T1C1=y1, T1C2=y2),
                      index=t)
    df.index.name = 'time'
    return df

df = read_data()

# Convert index to integer so datashader will work correctly.
df.index = df.index.values.astype(np.int64) / 1e6
class_names = [str(c) for c in sorted(df['cluster'].unique()) if int(c) >= 0]

def apply_formatter(plot, element):
         plot.handles['xaxis'].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter()

def get_points_data(feature):
    d = {}
    df.index.name = 'time'
    for cluster_num in class_names:
        subset = df.loc[df['cluster'] == int(cluster_num), feature].dropna()
        d[cluster_num] = hv.Points(data=subset.reset_index(), kdims=['time', feature])
    return hv.NdOverlay(d, kdims='k')

spec = {'plot': {'RGB': {'width': 800, 'height': 300,
                              'finalize_hooks': [apply_formatter],
                              # 'tools': 'pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,save,hover'
                              }
                      },
             'norm': {'RGB': {'framewise': True}}}

n_clusters = df['cluster'].nunique()
if n_clusters <= 20:
    colors = Category20[n_clusters]
else:
    num_repeats = n_clusters // 20 + 1
    colors = Category20[20] * num_repeats
    colors = colors[:n_clusters]

renderer = hv.Store.renderers['bokeh'].instance(mode='server', holomap='server')
DataSelector = hv.streams.Stream.define('feature', feature='T1C1')
data_stream = DataSelector(feature='T1C1')
dmap_points = hv.DynamicMap(get_points_data, streams=[data_stream])
rangexy = hv.streams.RangeXY(transient=True)
plotsize = hv.streams.PlotSize()
datashaded_points = dynspread(datashade(dmap_points, color_key=colors,
                                             streams=[rangexy, plotsize],
                                             aggregator=ds.count_cat('k'),
                                             min_alpha=0.1
                                             ), threshold=0.5, max_px=10).opts(spec)


renderer = hv.Store.renderers['bokeh'].instance(mode='server', holomap='server')
doc = curdoc()
plot = renderer.get_plot(datashaded_points, doc=doc)

doc.add_root(plot.state)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you set the RangeXY stream to be transient. I think that might be causing the issue since it resets the parameters to `None` after each event, and therefore default to the data range.

Comment: Indeed, setting that to False does fix it but I think I need that. In my full dashboard, I have a dropdown for choosing which feature to plot. The only way (I know of) to get it to autoscale when changing features it to have `transient=True`.